# Quick sort algorithm maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to implement the quicksort algorithm.

However i am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "quicksort.py", line 57, in <module>
    quick_sort(unsorted_list)   
   File "quicksort.py", line 25, in quick_sort
    quick_sort_helper(unsorted_list, lo, hi)
   File "quicksort.py", line 32, in quick_sort_helper
    quick_sort_helper(unsorted_list, lo, p)
   File "quicksort.py", line 32, in quick_sort_helper
    quick_sort_helper(unsorted_list, lo, p)
   File "quicksort.py", line 32, in quick_sort_helper
    quick_sort_helper(unsorted_list, lo, p)   [Previous line repeated 990 more times]   
   File "quicksort.py", line 29, in quick_sort_helper
    print(unsorted_list, lo, hi) 
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

```
def quick_sort(unsorted_list):

    lo = 0
    hi = len(unsorted_list) - 1
    quick_sort_helper(unsorted_list, lo, hi)

def quick_sort_helper(unsorted_list, lo, hi):

    if lo < hi:
        p = partition(unsorted_list, lo, hi)
        quick_sort_helper(unsorted_list, lo, p)
        quick_sort_helper(unsorted_list, p + 1, hi)

def partition(arr, lo, hi):

    pivot_index = int(len(arr) / 2)
    pivot = arr[pivot_index]
    i = lo
    j = hi

    while (i <= j):

        while i <= j and arr[i] <= pivot:
            i = i + 1

        while i <= j and arr[j] >= pivot:
            j = j - 1

        if i < j:
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

    arr[pivot_index], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[pivot_index]
    return j 

unsorted_list = [10, 16, 8, 12, 15, 6, 3, 9, 5]
quick_sort(unsorted_list)
print("end", unsorted_list)
```

Conceptually i think i understand the quicksort algorithm, but im not sure what is wrong with my implementation of it.

Comment: Since your error is quite small it cannot be that the recursion is too deep. So the only other explanation is that at your intervalls do not always decrease in size -> infinit recursion. -> Try to debug the left and right index of the intervals of your calls.

Comment: oops i updated the error message to include the entire trace

Comment: There seems to be some infinity recursion when hi becomes 4.
```
[3, 5, 8, 6, 9, 12, 10, 15, 16] 0 4
[3, 5, 8, 6, 9, 12, 10, 15, 16] 0 4
[3, 5, 8, 6, 9, 12, 10, 15, 16] 0 4
[3, 5, 8, 6, 9, 12, 10, 15, 16] 0 4
[3, 5, 8, 6, 9, 12, 10, 15, 16] 0 4
[3, 5, 8, 6, 9, 12, 10, 15, 16] 0 4
[3, 5, 8, 6, 9, 12, 10, 15, 16] 0 4
```

Comment: That last swap in `partition` looks suspicious to me. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: After partitioning you should exclude the pivot index just found from further processing.

Comment: Your `pivot_index` selection is based of the middle of the whole array, not the middle of the subarray you're supposed to be partitioning. That's going to break all sorts of stuff.

Comment: It's actually fine to pick the middle element as the pivot, but this is just for picking a value. Once you start partitioning, the pivot index here is `j`, which is also what is returned as a result. `pivot_index` is meaningless after its initial use.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - pivot is excluded for Lomuto partition scheme, but can end up anywhere with Hoare partition scheme such as the code above.

Comment: To follow up on the other comments use `pivot = arr[int(lo+hi)/2]` , and don't swap the index with arr[j] when done. The example code is a variation of Hoare partition scheme, elements <= pivot on the left, elements >= pivot on right, elements = pivot or pivot itself can end up anywhere, depending on data pattern.